# If statement in list dynamic creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
colors = [ (i % 2 == 0)? "W" else "B" for i in range(4000)]
```

The above is an invalid python syntax. But you get the goal, colors should be ["W", "B", "W",...] 4000 times.

If there a way to achieve this in a single line in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You just didn't have the syntax quite right.  Here's what you want:

```
colors = [ "W" if (i % 2 == 0) else "B" for i in range(4000)]
```

Result:

```
['W', 'B', 'W', 'B', 'W', 'B', 'W', 'B' ....
```

If you are going to iterate over the colors rather than really needing them all at once in an in-memory list, using a generator is better for both speed and memory consumption...

```
for color in ("W" if (i % 2 == 0) else "B" for i in range(20)):
    ...
```

Comment: Suggestion: `[color for _ in range(2000) for color in ('W', 'B')]`

Comment: @Chris: Simpler/faster: `['W', 'B'] * 2000`. Or for lazy iteration, `itertools.islice(itertools.cycle('WB'), 4000)`